# Scroll element in selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to focus on an element to make this element in the center of the screen or way from the top to be above the middle.
This is what I did

```
.FindElementById("toBePaid[" & r - 1 & "]").ExecuteScript "this.scrollIntoView(true); window.scrollBy(0, -(window.innerHeight - this.clientHeight)-150);"
```

But I couldn't see the element as it is at the top-most of the screen of the website.

I have tried too

```
.FindElementById("toBePaid[" & r - 1 & "]").ScrollIntoView True
```

But the same problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @QHarr I could dolve it

```
Function ScrollIntoViewCenter(element As WebElement)
  Const JS_SCROLL_CENTER = _
    "this.scrollIntoView(true);" & _
    "var y = (window.innerHeight - this.offsetHeight) / 2;" & _
    "if (y < 1) return;" & _
    "for (var e=this; e; e=e.parentElement) {" & _
    "  if (e.scrollTop == 0) continue;" & _
    "  var yy = Math.min(e.scrollTop, y);" & _
    "  e.scrollTop -= yy;" & _
    "  if ((y -= yy) < 1) return;" & _
    "}" & _
    "window.scrollBy(0, -y);"
  
  element.ExecuteScript JS_SCROLL_CENTER
End Function
```