# Click on JavaScript link with onclick attribute

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I have tried a  lot to find a solution to a link that has `onclick` attribute but I could noot find a clue
The HTML for the element like that

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dealSideLinkPage('/lawyerViews/lawOrders/newCase.jsp')">أمر أداء جديد</a>
```

I tried to use `ExecuteScript` but got error. I am using selenium in VBA
Trying this line doesn't work with me

```
.ExecuteScript "document.getElementByXPath(""//*[@id='SrvTabs1']/div/div/div[1]/nav/div/ul/li[3]/a"").click()"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as `أمر أداء جديد` using the `onclick` attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByLinkText*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByLinkText("أمر أداء جديد").click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByCss("a[onclick^='dealSideLinkPage'][onclick*='newCase']").click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'dealSideLinkPage') and text()='أمر أداء جديد']").click
  ```

Comment: I think the problem is related to the position of the element. For the first time in loop, it works well with no problem but in the second loop, the problem occurs `element click intercepted`. so how can I get to the top of the web page each time at the start of the loop?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Add some wait and retest please.

Comment: No the problem is not in the wait I am sure. When I go manually to the top of the webpage, the line works very well. I have tested that myself more than once.

Comment: How about implementing [ScrollIntoViewCenter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213243/scroll-element-in-selenium-vba)

Comment: I have found a better way which uses ExecuteScript too and this solved the problem `.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", .FindElementByXPath("//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'dealSideLinkPage') and text()='أمر أداء جديد']")`. Thank you very much for the great support.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Well :) honestly `ExecuteScript` should be your last option to fall back.

Comment: The problem is that the website is heavily javascript and I have no alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can try any of these XPaths -

```
//a[text()='أمر أداء جديد']

//a[contains(text(),'أمر أداء جديد')]
```

Note: Onclick and style attributes are not suggested to write XPath.